# About getParameters failed (empty parameters)

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I'm trying a camera capture application with SurfaceView.

The application's overview is

1. It can detect Face in realtime (on camera view).
2. It can store the movie.

I'm using android.media.MediaRecord class for saving the movie.

```
myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); 
myRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Movies/sample.3gp");
myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
myRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30); 
myRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240); 
myRecorder.prepare(); 
myRecorder.start();
```

after avobe step,RuntimeException occur in below step.(camera is android.hardware.Camera object)

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame: ");

    int width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width; <--
    int height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;


03-22 22:54:09.134 27875-27875/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: wbcompany.co.jp.facedetector3, PID: 27875
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
                                                   at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
                                                   at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:2019)
                                                   at wbcompany.co.jp.facedetector3.CameraView.onPreviewFrame(CameraView.java:150)
                                                   at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1192)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6189)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

before calling 'myRecorder.start()',this Exception doesn't occur.

I have no idea of this error's solution.
Please give me the solution of this problem.

My runtime enviroment:
 Android 7.0/ API level 24

Comment: In my case, I was getting this on the stock Camera app on an Android API 22 emulator. I fixed it by using the 32bit x86 OS image on the emulator instead of the 64bit x86 one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange error message, but the case is very real. When the camera is busy in MediaRecorder, it will not be accessible for other uses.

Generally speaking, access to camera parameters may be very inefficient on some devices. It is strongly recommended not to call `camera.getParameters()` for every preview frame. Create local fields in your CameraView class or in the activity that embeds it, and store width and height there when you start preview. They will not change unless you explicitly stop the camera and change its configuration.

If I am not missing something, your `onPreviewFrame()` callback happens on the main (UI) thread. The good practice is to call `Camera.open()` on a separate HandlerThread, to keep preview processing from slowing down UI.

Comment: I'm sorry for late response.Thank you for good information.I didn't know camera.getParametes() is not recommended.

Comment: getParameters() is perfectly good, but it is expensive and should not be used without discretion.

Comment: @AlexCohn, would you mind writing small example about the best usage of `getParameters()`? I am trying to write an app that turns on/off flashlight and found many people badly using this method without paying attention to its expensive call. Thanks